# Checkers - with customized starting setups and AI agents

Tags: variants, checkers

Does anyone know a Checkers program that allows customized starting setups when playing vs an AI?

My current app - Dammen (in Dutch) - has the possibility to customize the setup, but then I have to play both sides myself. If I could play against the computer, I could learn a great deal from it.

Comment: I'm not including this as an answer, because I'm unsure if it's entirely correct/what you are looking for, but I believe the Checkers application on the kindle store (for the kindle) has this option.

Answer (score 3):

I found a Windows program on https://dammen.startpagina.nl/ (checkers is called 'dammen'in Dutch). On this page I installed the program "dam 2.2". This is amazing. I can customize the setup (positions of the pieces on the board) and save the game. Then I can choose for two players, one player against the computer, or only the computer. This last option is awesome, because now I can learn from the computer what is best and see why it is so.

Comment: "learn from the computer what is best" - you cant learn what is best, just what is probably very good.  The AI do not play optimally from any position.  Checkers has been weakly solved: From the starting position, we have a computational proof that checkers is a draw.  

https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/317/5844/1518.full.pdf?casa_token=fP9QReDlUZgAAAAA:tu_6yU_rT3ntCLLXTBUzRsqEUSRc_OP00aJwHd5LQ808csPHsGpn1Aw2AKGmGrkpPLsj0jLGrj_Wc18

Comment: Thanks for the comment and interesting article. I am a beginner and did not know this, thanks!